# $F(\mathbf{x})$ is tangent to $z^2=x^2+y^2$ everywhere

Tags: 3d, curves, vector-fields

Show the vector field $F(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    \end{pmatrix}$ is tangent to the curve $z^2=x^2+y^2$ everywhere.

Geometrically, this is quite straightforward: the curve is made of two cones joined at their tips at the origin with aperture $\frac{\pi}{2}$, whilst $F(\mathbf{x})$ is a vector field which is going radially outwards, so the conclusion follows. Is there a way to show this algebraically, maybe using grad? What if the vector field and curve in question were not as easy to visualise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing $z^2=x^2+y^2$ I can let $S=x^2+y^2-z^2$, and then the equation becomes $S=0$. Think of $S=0$ as a surface in 3D; we can find a normal vector to that surface by computing $\nabla S$,
\begin{equation}
\nabla S=\begin{pmatrix}
2x\\2y\\-2z
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Now, $\nabla S$ is normal to the surface $S=0$, which is equivalent to saying $\nabla S$ is perpendicular to a vector $v$ if and only if $v$ is tangent to $S=0$. You can easily check that $\nabla S\cdot F=0$, which is enough to prove $F$ is a tangent vector everywhere.